# /bin/sh + "grep -o" + regular expression = single line output?

Tags: regex, awk, grep

after some investigation I have managed to find my wanted regular expression to work on /bin/sh - busybox:

**INPUT**:

```
Mar  8 09:58:29 mysuperhost kern.alert kernel: Rejected OUT -- IN=br0 OUT=vlan2 SRC=192.168.1.8 DST=3.26.211.8 LEN=95 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=648 PROTO=UDP SPT=22008 DPT=51413 LEN=75
```

**REGEXP**:

```
grep -o -E '((^.{0,16})|(IN=.\S*)|(IN=.\S*)|(OUT=.\S*)|(SRC=.\S*)|(DST=.\S*)|(PROTO=.\S*)|(SPT=.\S*)|(DPT=.\S*))'
```

Which gives me:

```
Mar  8 09:58:29
IN=br0
OUT=vlan2
SRC=192.168.1.8
DST=3.26.211.8
PROTO=UDP
SPT=22008
DPT=51413
```

The problem:
I don't seem to be able to have grep giving me the result on a single line

The wanted result:

```
Mar  8 09:58:29 IN=br0 OUT=vlan2 SRC=192.168.1.8 DST=3.26.211.8 PROTO=UDP SPT=22008 DPT=51413
```

Comment: You should use `awk` for this, instead of `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %s ",$1,$2,$3;for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/(IN|OUT|SRC|DST|PROTO|SPT|DPT)=/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
Mar 8 09:58:29 IN=br0 OUT=vlan2 SRC=192.168.1.8 DST=3.26.211.8 PROTO=UDP SPT=22008 DPT=51413
```

Just change whats in the `if` test to select fields you like.

Comment: This awk solution works like a charm! The only other think I can think (and this is not part of the original question) is: to improve the readability it would be nice to format the output with fixed fields so that SIP=1.2.3.4 and SIP=111.222.111.222 are actually one below the others.

Comment: @user3018558 Can be done, but needs to store date inn to variable before print out.